# PerfView: CPU MSec is 0 for all the processes

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-server-2012, perfview

I am running PerfView on Windows Server 2012. It is running on a VMware VM. As shown in the below image, the CPU is 0 for all the processes.

Where should I start debugging?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to troubleshoot with Perfview? In the events window there is an event for exception as well as for Perfview. I would also start exploring that.

Comment: CPU utilization is 100% on that machine. I am trying to understand which process is consuming the most & why?

Comment: @Sundeep Have you solved this problem? I have also experienced it, but on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/issues/1726) is relevant. From [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/issues/1726#issuecomment-1276697339):

> I just learned of a feature in Microsoft Defender that may cause the behavior you're seeing, as it takes the PMU from ETW. You can read more about it at https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2021/04/26/defending-against-cryptojacking-with-microsoft-defender-for-endpoint-and-intel-tdt/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-endpoint/defending-against-ransomware-with-microsoft-defender-for/ba-p/3243941.
>
> The feature can be disabled by running `powershell.exe Set-MpPreference -DisableTDTFeature $true`.

Long story short, run the following from Powershell:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableTDTFeature $true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't figure it out. So I deleted standalone exe, along with other perfview related zips and re-downloaded latest zip from the official microsoft website. Unzipped it and it started working again. This is definitely a bug.